# Python efficient way to check if very large string contains a substring

Tags: python, performance

Python is not my best language, and so I'm not all that good at finding the most efficient solutions to some of my problems. I have a very large string (coming from a 30 MB file) and I need to check if that file contains a smaller substring (this string is only a few dozen characters). The way I am currently doing it is:

```
if small_string in large_string:
    # logic here
```

But this seems to be very inefficient because it will check every possible sequence of characters in the file. I know that there will only be an exact match on a newline, so would it be better to read the file in as a list and iterate through that list to match?

EDIT: To clear up some confusion on "matching on a newline only", here's an example:

```
small_string = "This is a line"
big_string = "This is a line\nThis is another line\nThis is yet another"
```

If I'm not mistake, the in keyword will check all sequences, not just every line.

Comment: What do you mean by, "exact match on a newline"?

Comment: Do you want efficient use of space (memory) or efficiency of speed of finding a match? Different pattern matching algorithms have different characteristics in this regard.

Comment: @Jon: The example you gave will stop searching on the first line.

Comment: Why do you assume that `small in large` is implemented simplistically?  CPython developers often do a good job picking the best algorithm for built-in operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use one of these algorithms:

- [Rabin–Karp string search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm)
- [Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) (aka KMP) see an implementation [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117214-knuth-morris-pratt-string-matching/)

Although I believe KMP is more efficient, it's more complicated to implement.The first link includes some pseudo-code that should make it very easy to implement in python.

you can look for alternatives here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: Python already uses [a pretty fast C-level implementation of "a mix between boyer-moore and horspool"](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5444c2e22ff8/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h), so implementing a different string search algorithm at Python level is probably going to be several orders of magnitude slower.

Answer (score 19):

Is it really slow? You're talking about 30MB string; let's try it with even bigger string:

```
In [12]: string="agu82934u"*50*1024*1024+"string to be found"

In [13]: len(string)
Out[13]: 471859218

In [14]: %timeit "string to be found" in string
1 loops, best of 3: 335 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit "string not to be found" in string
1 loops, best of 3: 200 ms per loop
```

I wouldn't say that 335 ms is much time looking for substring in 450MB string.

Answer (score 13):

How slow is too slow? I just did an `a in b` test for a unique string at the end of a 170 MB string. It finished before my finger left the Enter key.

Answer (score 4):

I do not see how to make it more optimal on the comparison, to be honest. But you can use less memory and lose less time with I/O if you read the file line by line:

```
has_small_string = False
for line in large_file:
    if small_string in line:
        has_small_string = True
        break
if has_small_string:
   # ... Your stuff here ...
```

This is no revolutionary improvement, and can be even less useful if you *really* need the large string in the memory, but it *may* be helpful, so I am posting here :)

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check if that substring exists,

```
for line in open("file"):
    if substring in line:
         print "exists"
         sys.exit() # or break to do some other stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you implying that only a complete line will match? (your EDIT: matching on a newline only example seems to)

Then I imagine

```
for line in open('file').readlines():
  if line==small_string:
    return True
return False
```

IE,  using == is quicker than 'in' - perhaps. I wouldn't be surprised if the underlying implementation of in catches the case where the line to search and the string to search for are the same length and just attempts an == itself.

woudl be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
small_string = "This is a line"
big_string = "This is a line This is another line\nThis is yet another"

test= big_string.split("This is a line" ,1)

if len(test)==2:

    print "it`s there"

elif len(test)!=2:

    print "it`s not"
```

Answer (score -1):

I would rely on fast implementation by someone else:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT
import os

...
with open(os.devnull, 'w') as devnull:
    if subprocess.call('grep %s "%s"' % (smallstring, file), shell=True, stdout=devnull, stderr=STDOUT) == 0:
        pass #do stuff
```

Won't work on windows.

edit: I'm worried taht grep returns 0 wheter it finds something or not. But I don't have any shell available to me now so I can't test it.

Comment: that is so unnecessary, calling an external program.

Comment: grep does in fact return 0 when executed properly... @ghostdog74 it's the POSIX way... everything is put into modules and those modules are called whenever needed, it's the same as adding an import to your python file in most cases this is actually faster...