# find sequence in non tab delimited file

Tags: python, fasta

Today i encountered again a problem.

I have a file looking like:

File A

```
>chr1
ACGACTGACTGTCGATCGATCGATGCTCGATGCTCGACGATCGTGCTCGATC
>chr2
GTGACGCACACGTGCTAGCGCTGATCGATCGTAGCTCAGTCAG
>chr3
CAGTCGTCGATCGTCGATCGTCG
```

and so on (basicly a FASTA file).

In other file I have a nice tab delimited informations about my read:

File B

```
chr2 0 * 2S3M5I2M1D3M * CACTTTTTGTCTA NM:i:6
```

Both files are truly huge

I want write everything that needs to be done, only the part that I have a problem with:

if filed chr2 from File B matches line >chr2 in file A, look for CACTTTTTGTCTA (fileB) in sequence of file A (only in sequence in >chr2 region. Next >chr is a different chromosome so I don't want to search there).

To simplify this let's look for : CACACGTGCTAG sequence in file A

I was trying using dictionary for the file A, but it's completely not feasible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So, what you're doing now is creating a dictionary from file A, in which the keys are chromosomes and the values are DNA sequences? And then using something like "fileBField in fileAfield" to see if the sequence is in the value of the appropriate key?

Comment: yes, and it's very 'not smart'. However I digged .next method and made some improvement

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
for req in fileb:
   (tag, pattern) = parseB(req)
   tag_matched = False
   filea = open(file_a_name)
   for line in filea:
       if line.startswith('>'):
           tag_matched = line[1:].startswith(tag)
       elif tag_matched and (line.find(pattern) > -1)
           do_whatever()
    filea.close
```

Should do the job if you can write a parseB function.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary lookups are fast, so it seems like the part that's taking a long time must be searching within the sequence. string.contains() is implemented in C, so it's pretty efficient. If that's not fast enough, you'll probably need to go with an algorithm more specialized for efficiency, as discussed here: [Python efficient way to check if very large string contains a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175020/python-efficient-way-to-check-if-very-large-string-contains-a-substring)