# Python - Cost of find() function

Tags: python, find

I am looking for an effective way to check if a short string is in a long string. I saw some suggestions on this thread: 
[Python efficient way to check if very large string contains a substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175020/python-efficient-way-to-check-if-very-large-string-contains-a-substring)

However, I didn't see the use of find() there. Is it expensive to use find() function? What is the time complexity?

I've looked at the Wiki page but didn't find find() there. 
https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quickly perusing the source, it appears that [`str.find`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5444c2e22ff8/Objects/stringobject.c#l1742) calls [`stringlib_find_slice`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5444c2e22ff8/Objects/stringlib/find.h#l66) from [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5444c2e22ff8/Objects/stringobject.c#l1732) which eventually calls [`fastsearch`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5444c2e22ff8/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h#l36).  The actual algorithm is explained [here](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm) -- with python pseudo-code (which I gleaned from reading the comments).

It looks like the implementation is in worst case O(N*M) (The same as a naive approach), but can do O(N/M) in some cases (where N and M are the lengths of the string and substring respectively), and O(N) in frequent cases<sup>1</sup>.

<sup><sup>1</sup>(don't quote me on it -- I only skimmed the document)</sup>