# how to convert a string containing characters into date time using strptime in Python

Tags: python, regex, datetime, strptime

I'm trying to convert a string where there exists a characters between date information into a datetime. I was wondering if this is possible without using `replace` function. Suppose my string is defined as `'20220117A1745'` implying Jan. 17th, 2022 at 5:45pm.

If I use `strptime`, as expected, I receive an error.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(x,"%Y%m%d%H%M")
ValueError: unconverted data remains: A1745
```

I was wondering if I can do this without using another method. The reason why I don't want to use antoher method is that, `replace` has a bad time ecomplexity and will slow the execution time badly (see for [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583983/what-is-the-big-o-notation-for-the-str-replace-function-in-python)). I'll do this operation for hundreds of thousans of strings in a for loop.

Comment: Is there always 'A' in the same position?

Comment: just add `A` in middle `datetime.strptime(x,"%Y%m%dA%H%M")`

Comment: @whitepanda I had a solution to the question you just deleted inf you're still interested

Comment: @mozway I deleted it cuz chatgpt gave me the answer. However, I undeleted it in case you have a more efficient answer.

Comment: Hard to know without seeing your current answer… I hope it should be efficient. Note that ChatGPT provides a lot of flawed answers (seemingly correct but in fact non functional)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string **always** has 'A' in the same position then you can do this:

```
from datetime import datetime
x = '20220117A1745'
print(datetime.strptime(x,"%Y%m%dA%H%M"))
```

If you don't know what the letter is then:

```
print(datetime.strptime(x[:8]+x[9:],"%Y%m%d%H%M"))
```

**Output for both methods:**

```
2022-01-17 17:45:00
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
from datetime import datetime

x = '20220117A1745'
date_str = x[:8] + x[9:]
date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y%m%d%H%M')
print(date_obj)
```

which gives

```
2022-01-17 17:45:00
```