# Running time for string lookup

Tags: python, string, substring, big-o, lookup

In Python, what is the running time to lookup whether a character or substring is present in a string?

Example:

```
string = 'Hello World'
char = 'W'

if char in string:
    # do something
```

For this if condition, is the time complexity O(1) or O(S), where S is the length of the string?

Comment: If char is not in the string you look at every char so do you really think that could be a O(1)?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35220418/runtime-of-pythons-if-substring-in-string

Comment: Found that it is O(N)