# How to find the minimum possible cycle shift to take from s1 to s2?

Tags: python, string, algorithm, string-matching

If I have 2 strings `s1` and `s2`, where the `s2` is a cyclically shifted string of the `s1`. It needs to find the minimum possible cycle shift to take from `s1` to `s2`.

Let me show an example:

`s1 = 'I love cookies '`

`s2 = 'cookies I love '`
Here the answer is `7`.

It is preferable to take in linear time. There is my failed trials:

```
def find_minimum_cyclic_shift(s1, s2):

        if len(s1) != len(s2):
            return -1

        index = s2.index(s1[0])
        if (index > -1):
            if (s1==s2):
                return 0;

            #finalPosition = len(s2) - index
            #print(finalPosition, " index=",index)
            #return s2[0] == s1[finalPosition] and s1[finalPosition::]==s2[0:index]
        return index
```

But it doesn't work for the case: `absabsabsf` and `absfabsabs`. Instead of 4 I have 0. because index function returns me only the first appearing of a letter.

Please, give me at least a logic to code it.

Comment: Concatinate the string s1 with itself, and then use KMP algorithm on it for pattern matching to search for s2 in s1 + s1. KMP is O(n) in worst case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply use `find` on a doubled-string, like this:

```py
s1 = 'I love cookies '
s2 = 'cookies I love '

answer = min((s1*2).find(s2), (s2*2).find(s1))
print(answer)
```

Output:

```
7
```

(will print `-1` if `s2` is not a cyclic shift of `s1`).

The reason it works is that if `s2` is indeed a cyclic shift of `s1`, then concatenating `s1` to itself will contain `s2` somewhere in the middle.

Luckily, this "somewhere" is exactly the size of the shift required (the number of chars in `s1` that appear before `s2`'s first char).

We also need to check the "other direction" for a possibly shorter shift, so we take the minimum result from both possible directions (could technically use arithmetic to avoid the second search, if the result is `> n/2` then the answer is simply `n` - the result.

Note on runtime complexity: my solution does NOT guarantee a linear time, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35220792/5052365), it can take `O(N*N)` in the worst case.

Comment: Doubling the length of the string doesn't make it non-linear, and from there it depends on the string matching algorithm that `find` uses. there are definitely ones that take linear time, lemme try and look for a source

Comment: Ohh... I have also think about doubling and searching... But I am not aware of any linear time matching algorithm.

Comment: @YashShah you seem to be right, based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35220792/5052365, it's linear only on average case, but has non-linear worst case, will add this note to my answer

Comment: There are linear algorithms according to [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm#Basic_classification_of_search_algorithms)