# Which algorithm does str.find() uses to return the lowest index in Python?

Tags: python, string, search

I wanted to know what string search algorithm does the function `find()` in Python uses in order to find the lowest index of a substring.

I tried going through the source code on Github but there are so many matching `find` that I could not find the exact function. In the official doc, there is no link to the source code as well, just the explanation, unlike PySpark documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/find.h and fastsearch.h (which mentions *based on a mix between boyer-
   moore and horspool, with a few more bells and whistles on the top*)

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/26008904/9235482